# Why this transaction has extra characters in input data

Tags: transactions

In this transactions [0xa70ce6df9c08496dfb14eb9a90aee82a9d93c2a4385c990766ea9d91ed80127c](https://etherscan.io/tx/) input data is a call of swap function:

```
0000000000000000000000003208684f96458c540eb08f6f01b9e9afb2b7d4f0
0000000000000000000000005a3e6a77ba2f983ec0d371ea3b475f8bc0811ad5
000000000000000000000000de67d97b8770dc98c746a3fc0093c538666eb493
0000000000000000000000009ec9367b8c4dd45ec8e7b800b1f719251053ad60
00000000000000000000000008608176e1d6ac5be11de8403805d4b339899a1b
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000257c590a000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001724d6bd821
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000160
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f200a0
07e5c0d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ce00
006700206ae40711b8002dc6c09ec9367b8c4dd45ec8e7b800b1f719251053ad
602854fbda37ac17aa184772bca10d2ca731e06c8c0000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000015a3e6a77ba2f983ec0d371
ea3b475f8bc0811ad500206ae40711b8002dc6c02854fbda37ac17aa184772bc
a10d2ca731e06c8c1111111254eeb25477b68fb85ed929f73a96058200000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c02aaa39
b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc200000000000000000000000000000000
e26b9977
```

`0000000000000000000000003208684f96458c540eb08f6f01b9e9afb2b7d4f0 0000000000000000000000005a3e6a77ba2f983ec0d371ea3b475f8bc0811ad5 000000000000000000000000de67d97b8770dc98c746a3fc0093c538666eb493 0000000000000000000000009ec9367b8c4dd45ec8e7b800b1f719251053ad60 00000000000000000000000008608176e1d6ac5be11de8403805d4b339899a1b 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000257c590a000 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001724d6bd821 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000160 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f200a0 07e5c0d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ce00 006700206ae40711b8002dc6c09ec9367b8c4dd45ec8e7b800b1f719251053ad 602854fbda37ac17aa184772bca10d2ca731e06c8c0000000000000000000000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000015a3e6a77ba2f983ec0d371 ea3b475f8bc0811ad500206ae40711b8002dc6c02854fbda37ac17aa184772bc a10d2ca731e06c8c1111111254eeb25477b68fb85ed929f73a96058200000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c02aaa39 b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc200000000000000000000000000000000` - are ten parameters that are 32 bytes each

but what is this 8 characters at the end `e26b9977` ?

Even Etherscan does not use it when it decodes data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [ABI specification](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html), that input data ends at `...c756cc2`.

```
"types": [
    "address",
    "(address,address,address,address,uint256,uint256,uint256)",
    "bytes",
    "bytes"
  ]
```

The first 8 fixed length parameters are easy to guess because they have 32 bytes each. The two bytes arrays follows:

```
...000000140 
...000000160
```

The first bytes array is from byte offset `0x140` which points us to 32 bytes with value 0x0 meaning this byte array is blank.

The second byte array is from offset `0x160`, this points to the length of the array `...0000110` = `272 bytes`. Counting 272 bytes from the next 32-byte slot, the data ended at `c756cc2` and the last part `0x000...e26b9977` is ignored.

According to past answers here, extra data are ignored and does not cause error [Is it legal to include arbitrary bytes at the end of the DATA section executing a contract method?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47876/is-it-legal-to-include-arbitrary-bytes-at-the-end-of-the-data-section-executing)

About answer why, I think it could be either error in transaction encoding part or the possibility that the one who crafts that transaction use it for some extra logic off-chain (for example, their own script tracks different txs based on this extra data). Looking at similar txs to 1inch, it's likely that 1inch frontend does this intentionally.